# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS - Other side can't hear from headset

Tags: ubuntu, microphone

When i plugin headset in the jack and open any audio/video, I'm able to hear the audio being played. While when i connect to skype, bluejeans and do audio testing, i am unable to hear my own voice. Unfortunately one of my interview was messed out due to this issue. Can you please help me and let me know if you need any other details?

I've tried multiple links [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9YxMHIRDoY) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working) as well but that didn't helped. Volume under settings - sound - input and output are full and not mute.